# C++:Same code,different result

Tags: c++

Today my classmate ask me to help her debug her code as following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<Woker> A;
    int a;
    a = read_txt("234",A);
    if( a==-1 )
    {
        cerr<<"wrong"<<endl;
    }
//  else
//  {
//      print(A);
//  }
    return 0;
}

int read_txt(string filename,vector<Woker> & A)
{
    ifstream in(filename);
    if( !in )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while( !in.eof())
    {
        Woker temp;
        in >>temp.ID>>temp.Name>>temp.Salary>>temp.WorkYears;
        A.push_back(temp);
    }
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I run it on mycomputer,it always print

```
wrong
```

However I copy this code in another file,and run it.I get the following:

```
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Is there anyone can tell me what cause this different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first result means that, on your computer, there is no file called `"234"`; so the function returns immediately without entering the buggy loop.

The second result is probably because the loop tests for the "end of file" condition (but wrongly: you should test *after* trying to read, since the condition is only set when you try to read past the end), but doesn't test for any other errors. If any of the input is wrong, so that reading with `>>` fails, the loop will continue forever inserting copies of `temp` after each failed read. Eventually you'll run out of memory, which is indicated by throwing a `bad_alloc` exception.

A more correct version of the loop would be:

```
Woker temp;
while (in >>temp.ID>>temp.Name>>temp.Salary>>temp.WorkYears) {
    A.push_back(temp);
}
```

which will end either at the end of the file, or when any input fails. You could check `in.eof()` and `in.fail()` afterwards if you want to report errors.